# How do I use multiple webcams at once on Mac OS X?

Tags: usb, webcam

I have programmed a Flash app that makes use of several webcams at the same time. The app works great on Windows. When I try to use more than one webcam on Mac OS X, I find that each webcam I plug into the computer disables the previously attached webcam.

It appears that I can only have one USB camera working at a time. Is this correct? Is there any way of bypassing this?

Answer (score 4):

There are Mac applications that can do this, although I don't believe that any of them run on Flash.

Here's some that I found:

- [Wirecast](http://www.telestream.net/wire-cast/overview.htm) from Telestream
- [BoinxTV](http://www.boinx.com/boinxtv/overview/) from Boinx Software
- [CamCamX](http://b-l-a-c-k-o-p.com/CamCamX.html) from Black-Op

They're all commercial, but there's a wide range of pricing between the three.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where one USB camera would work and the other camera wouldn't.  After playing around with this I found out it was because I was using a USB-C hub and plugging both cameras into the same hub.  Either the hardware or OS supported only one camera per Macbook USB-C port.

I put the cameras through two separate USB-C hubs and they worked fine.

I'm using a newer Macbook and was attempting keep it simple to plug everything through one plug, but if I really want to use the two cameras simultaneously it seems this is impossible.